# Ember: Run-loop: How to know if a job is scheduled or complete

Tags: ember.js

```
scheduleOnce('afterRender', function x() {
    // Do something
});
```

Let's say I've scheduled a job (function x) like this and go to some other function (an event callback). Inside that, how do I know the above job's status (eg., scheduled, completed)?

Comment: you don't. You would manually have to set some state. But why do you even need this?

Answer (score 2):

You could put a flag inside the callback.

```
scheduleOnce('afterRender', () => {
 doSomething();
 this.hasRun = true;
});
```

Another more Ember solution would be to use a task here as tasks keep track of their state automatically.

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { task } from 'ember-concurrency';

export default Component.extend({
  myTask: task(function * (){
    yield doSomething();
    return true;
  }).on('afterRender')
});


{{#if myTask.lastSuccessful.value}}
  //only shows up after the task has run at least once
{{/if}}
```

More info at http://ember-concurrency.com

Comment: Definitely look into ember-concurrency, it also gives you the ability to enqueue tasks and comes with some nifty utilities like .drop() which helps avoid subsequent requests when the current task is still running:

```js
myTask: task(function * (){
    yield doSomething();
    return true;
  }).drop() 
```